# class/subject/course of chemistry

Tags: word-usage

Please, explain what is the appropriate word here.

> But it was the **class**/**subject**/**course** of chemistry that really interested him. At the age of 15, he went to college to study it.

Comment: Can you give us the sentence before? It would help us advise you.

Comment: Saying *I'm interested in the subject of chemistry* is a bit like saying *I live in the country of England*. Normally, we'd just say *I'm interested in chemistry* or *I live in England*.

Comment: The sentence before  - "As a child he had many hobbies, including model making and phitography.
It's from A2 Key test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, one can be ["interested in chemistry"](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=epCUXaWcFcTOwALgpr-oCA&q=site%3Aedu%20%22interested%20in%20chemistry%22&oq=site%3Aedu%20%22interested%20in%20chemistry%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...25039.37879..38466...0.2..0.196.2940.41j3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.XPgU3E4xOHI&ved=0ahUKEwilwbvMwv3kAhVEJ1AKHWDTD4UQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), and not likely in ["chemistry class"](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=N5GUXdS-IMyiwALgvLXABA&q=site%3Aedu%20%22interested%20in%20chemistry%20class%22&oq=site%3Aedu%20%22interested%20in%20chemistry%20class%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1314.5942..6219...1.2..0.80.722.11......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.Ktw6E_KkYwI&ved=0ahUKEwiUttamw_3kAhVMEVAKHWBeDUgQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) or ["subject."](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=e5GUXYivBorYwQKNo6jwCA&q=site%3Aedu%20%22interested%20in%20chemistry%20subject%22&oq=site%3Aedu%20%22interested%20in%20chemistry%20subject%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4517.18085..25086...0.2..0.80.1598.25......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.vpuRkbIeRcw&ved=0ahUKEwjI2PLGw_3kAhUKbFAKHY0RCo4Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) One can ["*take* a chemistry class"](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=RZOUXfi-IIXSwQLR1pygBw&q=site%3Aedu%20%22take%20a%20chemistry%20class%22&oq=site%3Aedu%20%22take%20a%20chemistry%20class%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1798.2292..2516...0.2..0.84.265.4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.cq5afQrN3U8&ved=0ahUKEwi49b6hxf3kAhUFaVAKHVErB3QQ4dUDCAs&uact=5), though. So, I suggest "But it was chemistry that really interested him."

The term "[chemistry course](http://site:edu)" is usually used for high school or university or out of school chemistry lessons.

Comment: Do you mean 'the couse of chemistry' is better here? It's taken from A2 Key, so one of the options should suit.

Comment: Your previous sentence says "As a child he had many hobbies, including model making and phitography," in which "model making" and "phitography" appear as such (without a class or course), so in the next sentence "chemistry" alone seems to be most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Subject, because it is the whole field of chemistry that interests him and not one (for example) particular class with a particular teacher.  (Although depending the preceding sentence, it would probably be more common to simply say, "But it was chemistry that really interested him.")

Contrast with: "His chemistry class interested him more than his math class."